# Return result between Windows Forms in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two Windows Forms (MyApp, Generator), and I need to call Generator from MyApp

```
Form gen = new Generator();
gen.Show();
string result = gen.IDontKnowWhatToDoHere();
```

My Generator.cs Form has three TextBox and a Button Ok, so when the user type some text in the three TextBoxes an click Ok I want to get the the Text typed in those three TextBoxes.

Do you have any ideas how I can achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the Ok button will close form or not?

Comment: I think yes it will do : this.Close(), but I can't invoke the onClose Event ?

Comment: Are you need modal dialog? It's mean that call code will wait until shown form closed.

Comment: I don't care, I need just a solution for my problem using modal or without.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class Generator : Form
{
    public string Text1 { get; private set; }

    void ok_Click (object sender, EventArgs)
    {
        this.Text1 = txt1.Text;
        ...
        this.Close();
    }
}

Form gen = new Generator();
gen.ShowDialog();
string text1 = gen.Text1;
...
```

---

```
class TextInfo
{
    public string Text1 { get; set; }
    ...
}

class Generator : Form
{
    public TextInfo Textinfo { get; private set; }

    public Generator(TextInfo info)
    {
        this.TextInfo = info;
    }

    void ok_Click (object sender, EventArgs)
    {
        this.TextInfo.Text1 = txt1.Text;
        ...
        this.Close();
    }
}

TextInfo info = new TextInfo();
Form gen = new Generator(info);
gen.ShowDialog();
string text1 = info.Text1;
```

Comment: I did this but text1 = "" because the MyApp form is not waiting the Generator Form to send data, so text1 is empty.

Comment: How can I make the MyApp wait the Generator form to close before it continue execution ?

Comment: You should use Form.ShowDialog instead of From.Show

Answer (score 9):

I generally use this pattern:

```
TResult result = Generator.AskResult();

class Generator : Form
{
    // set this result appropriately
    private TResult Result { get; set; }
    public static TResult AskResult()
    {
        var form = new Generator();
        form.ShowDialog();
        return form.Result; // or fetch a control's value directly
    }
}
```

This makes it work in a single statement, similar to a MessageBox, and does not require making any controls public. You can also include any additional data as parameters to the static method and pass them to the form's constructor or set properties appropriately.

Another benefits includes the ability to, if the need arises, reuse instances of the form.

Answer (score 2):

If you need data from a no modal form you should use events or other notification pattern.

```
class OkPressedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
   public OkPressedEventArgs(string text1, string text2, string text3)
   {
      Text1 = text1;
      Text2 = text2;
      Text3 = text3;
   }

   public string Text1 {get;private set;}
   public string Text2 {get;private set;}
   public string Text3 {get;private set;}
}

class SourceForm : Form
{
   public event EventHandler<OkPressedEventArgs> OkPressed;
   private void OnOkPressed()
   {
      if(OkPressed != null)
      {
          OkPressed(this, new OkPressedEventArgs(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox2.Text);
      } 
   }

   private void okButton_Click(object source, EventArgs e)
   {
       OnOkPressed();
   }
}

class TargetClass
{
   void ShowFormMethod()
   {
      var form = new SourceForm();
      form.OkPressed += OkPressedHandler;
      form.Show();
   }

   private void OkPressedHandler(object source, OkPressedEventArgs e)
   {
      // process form data here!
   }
}
```

Comment: This should be the answer as it explicitly clarifies what to do with non-modal forms, which is what you use Form.Show() for, as the OP did.

Answer (score 1):

```
Form gen = new Generator();
gen.ShowDialog();
string result = gen.IDontKnowWhatToDoHere();
```

But i think is more effectives been create delegate.

Answer (score 0):

IF Generator is a form so it inherits from Form, change the line to:

```
Generator gen = new Generator();
gen.Show();
string result = gen.SomePublicVariableOrProperty;
```

Comment: string result = gen.SomePublicVariableOrProperty; this should be called on onCLose event of generator

Comment: You need showdialog and not show. Or use OnClose event (what Gabrield says)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try by passing the Current Form instance as parameter to the constructor of the `Generator` form.

Once you have filled in the `Textbox` on click of the event Assign it to the Property in Main Form with the help of the instance which was passed in the constructor.

```
Form gen = new Generator(this);
gen.Show();

public Generator(Form F1)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    form1 = F1 as ParentForm; // now you have parent reference
}
```

Button Click of the `Generator` form

`form1.Somproperty` *assign the values*

Hope this helps