# Using a value from a closed form in a class

Tags: c#, winforms, oop

I'm trying to get some values of string variables from a form that will be closed. Form is used to get company info from the user. Those values will be used in a class to create a pdf. I have tried many things, I haven't been able to do it since I believe I have a problem in understanding OOP fully. Here is my trial:

In the form to be closed:

```
MyClass MyCls = new MyClass();

private void FrmCompanyInfo_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyCls.AssignValues(LogoFileName_, CompanyName_, CompanyAddress_);
    }
```

LogoFileName_, CompanyName_, CompanyAddress_ are strings holding values from textboxes.

This is the part of my class:

```
public class MyClass
{

    private string LogoFileName { get; set; }
    private string CompanyName { get; set; }
    private string CompanyAddress { get; set; }

    public void AssignValues(string LFN, string CN, string CA)
    {
        LogoFileName = LFN;
        CompanyName = CN;
        CompanyAddress = CA;
    }

            if (LogoFileName != null)
            {
               //it goes...
```

After closing the form, the variables in the class become null. For instance, the if condition above is not satisfied.

Could you please point out my mistake, or suggest me a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should do that in the Form.Closing event not the Form.Closed.

EDIT: For more details on how to do that, see [this answer and question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20904933/pass-object-to-main-form-when-i-close-it/20905391#20905391). You should not declare the object on the form that is closed, but on the calling form.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5989587/266143): if your form is meant to populate an instance of `CopmanyInfo`, you might want to consider a pattern like this:

```
public partial class CompanyInfoForm
{
    public static CompanyInfo ShowEditCompany()
    {
        var form = new CompanyInfoForm();
        form.ShowDialog();      
        return form.EditingCompany;
    }
}
```

Where `EditingCompany` may be a property that is built by reading the appropriate `TextBox` values. Then you can reuse the form:

```
var companyInfo = CompanyInfoForm.ShowEditCompany();
```

Comment: Thank you, but sorry, I don't get your solution, neither on the link. It can be crystal clear for you. What is the purpose of 'public static CompanyInfo ShowEditCompany()'. I don't understand why I should use 'form.ShowDialog()'.